# upload images useing the chevereto api with php

Tags: php

i am trying to upload images  from my server to the img server where chevereto  is installed but i cant get it to work

here is my code so far :

```
 $directory = "/var/www";
 $images = glob($directory . "/*.jpg");
foreach($images as $image)
{
  echo $image;
  $data =  base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));

  $run= shell_exec("curl --location --request POST \"http://ip/api/1/upload/?key=123456789&source=$data&format=json\"");
print_r($run);

}
```

getting error : `414 Request-URI Too Large`

here is the api documentation : https://chevereto.com/docs/api-v1

Comment: FYI, PHP has its own [curl library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). You shouldn't run it from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `POST` request method, but you are sending the `source parameter in URL`. 
The `$data` in your URL is base64 encoded, which results in a very large string. That's why you are getting the error `414 Request-URI Too Large`.

**Solution:**

You should change the params to JSON body using the same POST method.

From the documentation of `chevereto` that you provided it is made clear.

> API v1 calls can be done using the POST or GET request methods but since GET request are limited by the maximum allowed length of an URL you should prefer the POST request method.

So use POST method with JSON Body containing the parameters as `key:value` pair. That will solve the issue.

**Sample PHP Code:**

```php
$requestData = [
    'key' => 123456789,
    'source' => 'base64EncodedStringHere',
    'format' => 'json'
];

$jsonData = json_encode($jsonData);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://ip/api/1/upload",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jsonData,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```